# The most compact way to find an element in container with the minimum value of given field

Tags: c++, boost-bind

Let's we need to find an element with the minimum value of given field.

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/min_element.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Item
{
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
};

struct CompareByA
{
    bool operator()(const Item& x, const Item& y) const
    {
        return x.a < y.a;
    }
};

std::vector<Item> items;
//... fill
std::vector<Item>::const_iterator minA = boost::min_element(items, CompareByA());
```

What is the most compact way to do it using **boost::bind** or other boost features without explicit predicate struct declaration?
Maybe something like std::less and boost::bind(&Item::a) combination.

NOTE: Without using C++11 features.

Comment: With [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) and its *projection*, it would be `auto it = ranges::min_element(items, std::less<>{}, &Item::a);` but that does fit your requirements.

Comment: For the *most compact* answer, perhaps you should turn to the experts over at [codegolf.se] - but do be careful to read their help, and use the sandbox (they do like very precise questions!)

Comment: The most compact is not required, "boost::min_element(items, boost::bind(&Item::a, _1) < boost::bind(&Item::a, _2))", mentioned below, suits and quite convenient for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/min_element.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Item
{
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
};

std::vector<Item> items;
//... fill
std::vector<Item>::iterator minA = 
    boost::min_element(items, boost::bind(&Item::a, _1) < boost::bind(&Item::a, _2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create those helper:

```
template <typename T, typename M>
class CompareByMember
{
public:
    explicit CompareByMember(M m) : m(m) {}

    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const
    {
        return x.*m < y.*m;
    }
private:
    M m;
};

template <typename T, typename Ret>
CompareByMember<T, Ret (T::*)> MakeCompareByMember(Ret (T::*m))
{
    return CompareByMember<T, Ret (T::*)>(m);
}
```

And then call

```
std::vector<Item>::const_iterator minA =
    boost::min_element(items, MakeCompareByMember(&Item::a));
```

Comment: It's a good way to solve a problem. I was looking for something like this in boost implementation, but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a function:

```
bool compare_by_a(Item const& x, Item const& y)
{
  return x.a < y.a;
}

// ...

std::vector<Item>::const_iterator minA = boost::min_element(items, compare_by_a);
```

Comment: Yes.
But "without explicit predicate struct declaration" was written inexactly.
"Without explicit predicate struct or function declaration" was implied.